# MongoDB pymongo update() simply creates a new record rather than updating

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

Create a new document

> ```
> >>>Categories.insert({'test':'test'})
> ObjectId('506b563df49a007f73000001')
> ```

Yep, created OK.

> ```
> >>> Categories.find_one({'test':'test'})
> {u'test': u'test', u'_id': ObjectId('506b4149f49a007cd0000000')}
> ```

Give it a new attribute 'newAttr' with value 'hello'

> ```
> >>> Categories.update({'_id':Categories.find_one({'test':'test'})['_id']},{'newAttr':'hello'})
> ```

Find the same document

> ```
> >>> Categories.find_one({'test':'test'})
> {u'test': u'test', u'_id': ObjectId('506b563df49a007f73000001')}
> ```

It hasn't been updated??

Search for something containing the new attribute:

> ```
> >>> Categories.find_one({'newAttr':'hello'})
> {u'newAttr': u'hello', u'_id': ObjectId('506b4149f49a007cd0000000')}
> ```

Its created a separate document instead of updating the previous one??

Any idea how to correct this?

Comment: if you wanted to add a new field you need to use {$set:{'field':'name'}) - the way you have it is you are telling it to update the document to a whole new value...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't get the same you get when setting a new field, but I'm using this syntax:

`cat.update({'_id':cat.find_one({'test':'test'})['_id']},{'$set':{'newattr':'hello'}})`

See [here](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html) for $set explanation.

```
>>> cat.find_one({'test':'test'})
{u'newattr': u'hello', u'test': u'test', u'_id': ObjectId('506b5d07594bc07d90000000')}
```